# ¿Cómo generar un número o código aleatorio con un button en html y pasarlo a un input? O si es que mongodb puede generar números random

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

```
<script>
    function getRandomInt() {
    let start = 100
    let end = 9999
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = getRandomBetween(parseInt(start), parseInt(end));
    }
    function getRandomBetween(start, end) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1)) + start;
    }
 </script>
```

Al yo darle al botón debe generar un número o código random e insertarlo al input.
El problema es que al generar una reserva debe tener un código así como en una factura, y ese código o número aleatorio quiero ponerlo en un input para después darle a guardar todos los datos.

---

```html
<hr>
  <label>Codigo de Reserva</label>
  <input type="text" name="codigo" id="number" class="number" readonly>
  <button type="button" onclick="getRandomInt">Generar Codigo</button>
<hr>
```

Comment: Si a ese número aleatorio lo necesitas en el backend para guardarlo o procesarlo te recomiendo que lo generes en el backend y no en el frontend. Por un tema de seguridad, ya que cualquier dato que venga del frontend puede ser alterado por algún usuario mailcioso. Una regla de seguridad de aplicaciones es siempre desconfiar de los inputs que envía un usuario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `Math.random()` de JavaScript para generar un número aleatorio entre 0 y 1, y luego multiplicar ese número por un valor máximo para obtener un número aleatorio entre 0 y ese valor máximo.

Una vez que tienes la función que genera el número aleatorio, puedes asignarla al evento `onclick` del botón en tu página HTML, de manera que se ejecute cada vez que el usuario haga clic en el botón. Por ejemplo, tu código HTML podría verse algo así:

```html
<button onclick="generateRandomNumber()">Generar número aleatorio</button>
<input type="text" id="randomNumberInput">

<script>
  function generateRandomNumber() {
    // Genera un número aleatorio entre 0 y 100
    var randomNumber = Math.random() * 100;

    // Asigna el número aleatorio al input
    document.getElementById('randomNumberInput').value = randomNumber;
  }
</script>
```

En este ejemplo, al hacer clic en el botón, se ejecutará la función `generateRandomNumber()`, que generará un número aleatorio entre 0 y 100 y lo asignará al input con id `randomNumberInput`.